# EmguCV + Unity Open WebCam is Error;

Tags: unity-game-engine, webcam, emgucv

I use EmguCV  open webcam in unity. 
But it's fps is low much.

### this is my code ↓

```
private Texture2D texture;
private Capture capture;
private Color32[] color = new Color32[640*480];
// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    texture = new Texture2D (640, 480);
    capture = new Capture ();
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {

    Image<Bgr, Byte> currentFrame = capture.QueryFrame();
    Bitmap bitmapCurrentFrame = currentFrame.ToBitmap();
    Image<Bgra, Byte> img = new Image<Bgra, Byte> (bitmapCurrentFrame);


    for(int y=0; y<480; y++){
        for(int x=0; x<640; x++){

            int index = y+x*480;
            print(index+";"+x+";"+y);
            //byte b  = img.Data[x,y,0];
            color[index].r = img.Data[x,y,2];
            color[index].g = img.Data[x,y,1];
            color[index].b = img.Data[x,y,0];
            color[index].a = 0xff;
        }
    }
    texture.SetPixels32 (color);
    texture.Apply (false);
    renderer.material.mainTexture = texture;
}
```

i don't know why fps is so low...

and why my boss like EmguCV with Unity, why he don't use Unity-WebCamTexture...

OKAY,i really thank you for your read.

Hope, I can get some answer.

Answer (score 0):

Look at [`Texture2D.LoadRawTextureData`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Texture2D.LoadRawTextureData.html). It has no proper docs, so here's a snippet:

```
Texture2D tex = new Texture2D(width, height, format, false, true);
tex.LoadRawTextureData(buffer);
tex.Apply(false, true);
```

`Buffer` must be in the correct hardware format. For the `format` variable look at [the list of formats that unity accepts](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/TextureFormat.html).